# Error Importing from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, tfs, migration

When I try to import TFS to an on-premises TFS, I am getting an error after running the below cmd.

```
TFSConfig CloudImport /SQLInstance:SQLServerInstanceName /SettingsFile:SettingsFileName.ini
```

Error: "TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step Download bacpac from Azure Storage for component CloudImport during CloudImport: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Below are the instructions I followed to import TFS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cb80f0d-0119-4277-82e8-719a8db1796e

Comment: This is a Microsoft supported feature, you might be better requesting help on the MSDN forums where MS tech support reside.

Comment: I did request Microsoft about it. In the mean time, I wanted to see if anyone had the same or similar issue. Most of the time stackoverflow has better answers and faster responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally figured it out. Our internal encryption algo was not supported by Microsoft TFS cloud. So we had to stop that service and then import the data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Visual Studio Online export has expired. Try requesting a fresh one.

Comment: We finally figured it out. Our internal encryption algo was not supported by Microsoft TFS cloud. So we had to stop that service and then import the data. Thanks for your answer though.